# check object of array has one key or more dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect if object inside array has a key or not even I don't know the key of object?

example :

```
var a = [{}]
var b = [{a:1}] /* or [{a:1},{b:1}] or [{b:1}] */

if(a){ return false }
else if(b){ return true }
```

if I used `.length` the result will be `1`

> Note: the key is `dynamically`

Comment: @HMR does `Array.prototype.some` still `return true` if the `string` does not match with the key of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the keys (in array form). Use `length` to get the number of keys

```js
var a = [{}]
var b = [{a: 1}] 

if (Object.keys(a[0]).length) console.log('a[0] has keys');
else console.log('a[0] has no keys');

if (Object.keys(b[0]).length) console.log('b[0] has keys');
else console.log('b[0] has no keys');
```

---

If some of the objects on the has keys, some have none, you can use `some`

```js
let hasKeys = a => {
  return a.some( o => Object.keys(o).length );
}
 
let a = [{}];  //false
let b = [{a: 1}];  //true
let c = [{},{}]; //false
let d = [{a:1},{b:1}]; //true
let e = [{},{b:1}]; //true
 
console.log( 'a' , hasKeys( a ) );
console.log( 'b' , hasKeys( b ) );
console.log( 'c' , hasKeys( c ) );
console.log( 'd' , hasKeys( d ) );
console.log( 'e' , hasKeys( e ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it, because I want to control the amount of keys involved. Otherwise, if you need only to know whether there are any keys in an object, just use `.some()` like already pointed out.

```js
const a = [{}];
const b = [{foo:1}];
const c = [{bar:1, foz: 1, baz: 1}];
const d = [{beep:1}, {boop:2}];

const getAmountOfKeys = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((item) => Object.keys(item).length).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

console.log(`a has ${getAmountOfKeys(a)} keys`);
console.log(`b has ${getAmountOfKeys(b)} keys`);
console.log(`c has ${getAmountOfKeys(c)} keys`);
console.log(`d has ${getAmountOfKeys(d)} keys`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
const anyObjectHasKey = (key,array) => 
  array.some(o=>(o&&Object.keys(o).some(k=>k===key)))

const a = [{}];
const b = [{a: 1}];
console.log("a in a",anyObjectHasKey("a",a));
console.log("a in b",anyObjectHasKey("a",b));
```